# Why don't we say "Я слышал её говорившей"?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, phrase

When looking at phrases in the form of "verb - pronoun - participle":

> - Увидел его гуляющим
> - Застал его пьющим
> - Представил его улыбающимся

We use some verbs of perception, but not others.  For example we don't use the verb "hear" *(слышать/услышать)* We can say:

> - Я слышал её
> - Я слышал её голос
>
>   **But not**
> - Я слышал её разговаривавшей / шептавшей / болтавшей

Does there exist some anti-pattern in the language to not use the verb **"hear",** and possibly other verbs in such phrases?

Comment: *Застать* and *представить* are as fundamentally visual as *увидеть*. I'd say it's just that particular mode of perception.

Comment: это ооочень неблагодарное дело пытаться объяснить, почему какой-то конструкции не существует в языке - но наблюдение хорошее

Comment: You can use it, there's nothing wrong with it. A bit unusual though.

Comment: @Abakan a bit unusual is an underestimation though )

Comment: @shabunc Well, Я слышал её поющей is totally okay.

Comment: @Abakan and this is exactly what this question is about - why in some cases it's ok and in some it sounds unnatural

Comment: Is it? Can you give at least one example from ruscorpora, besides your inventions, with any words?

Comment: @shabunc Question is about verbs, not cases. And it's okay to use "слышать" in such kind of phrases. So the question is based on a wrong presumption.

Comment: I searched ruscorpora before posting the question. I didn't find any such phrases with verbs *слышать / услышать*

Comment: @Abakan - in some cases - в некоторых случаях

Comment: @Vitaly, управление разное у глаголов. You can't say слышать кого? Каким? Видеть кого?каким?is possible, not always I think.

Comment: But if you use a participle clause, any verb works.

Comment: @shabunc There is no "in some cases" in the question. There are "some verbs ". So as I said - the question is based on a wrong presumption.

Comment: @V.V. Here is an example for "слышать кого" - `"Это было немного, но он первый из смертных слышал его."` (Даниил Гранин, Зубр).  Also I could not find any examples using participle clauses either.

Comment: @Abakan `"Я слышал её поющей"` Google provides 4 references for this phrase.  And all of them are questions about proper translations.

Comment: @Vitaly This proves or disproves nothing (except that there are less than 5 referencesin Google). Everyone can build a phrase which is absolutely correct and is not referenced in Google.

Comment: @Vitaly, and where's a participle? Google doesn't count. I tried видеть and found 5 examples with reflexive participles only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is totally grammatical and correct to say so, but in modern language you usually would say "*я слышал, как она говорила...*". I think there is some nuance here.

Consider the following setting. She is the factory manager. Now consider the phrases:

> Я видел её говорившей с рабочими.
>
> Я видел, как она говорила с рабочими.

Both can mean the same, you saw her talking to the workers. But the second one can also mean you saw *how* she was talking to the workers. Her manners, mimic, tone. If you want exclude this, you use the first one. It is momentary: this can mean you say her face was red, but you cannot say anything about time-prolonged details.

Now what about *слышал* instead of *видел*? Well, the same,

> Я слышал её говорившей с рабочими.

means you heard some short moment of their conversation, by chance, like through a wall or by hearing their telephone call accidentally, but you cannot say in what manner and how she was speaking.

One more to note. *Я слышал её говорившей* can mean either once or several times, while *я слышал*, *как она говорила* can imply either only one (without referring to the manners) or referring to the manners (then likely not once).

Comment: I completely agree, that phrases with `как` are more common / natural.

Comment: `It is totally grammatical and correct to say so...` I'm willing to accept that my assumption is wrong, but I'm puzzled why my search on ruscorpora shows no examples of someone using such a phrase.

Comment: @Vitaly because you usually do not momentary hear somebody talkig. Try searching "я видел её говорившей"

Comment: Indeed such phrase is used, albeit infrequently.  After more digging in ruscorpora I found:

`Она никогда не слышала его разговаривающим с нею таким образом. [Н. Э. Гейнце. "Аракчеев" (1898)]`

`Но она еще не слыхала меня говорящим... [Н. И. Махно. Воспоминания (1929)]`

`До тех пор я почти никогда не слыхал ее поющую... [Ф. М. Достоевский. Дневник писателя. (1876)]`

This answer is accepted, because of a comment *"but in modern language you usually would say..."* References that I found are somewhat old.
+1 to everyone who said that such phrase is valid.

Comment: The last paragraph describes it all.

Answer (score 2):

`Я слышал её говорившей о [чём-либо]` sounds totally okay to my ear.

If, for example, you happened to catch a speech on some topic.

I think the weirdness comes from `слышал` and `говорившей`, which are both about sounds and therefore redundant. Maybe the better one would be:

`Я видел её говорившей о [чём-либо]`

Comment: alamar, Thank you for you response.  However, when I search on Google.  I get a response "No results found for "Я слышал её говорившей о" "  Could you please provide a supporting reference from National Corpus, or another source.

Comment: More natural would be "я слышал, как она говорила..."

Comment: @alamar, I think you could be right about the cause of the weirdness.  Both verbs are about sounds.  `Я видел его смотрящим` sounds equally strange.

Comment: @Vitaly google has results on `слышал его говорившим` and `видел её говорившей`.

Comment: @alamar  Interestingly, Google search results for `слышал его говорившим` are using the phrase with negation.  Just like ruscorpora examples.

Answer (score 0):

**Я видел её** describes *direct perception* of 'her', not derived from the idea 'I watched the vision of her' (я видел её изображение).

Я **слышал** её **голос** (or *как она говорит/говорила*) directly describes just *sound perception*, while **я слышал её** is an idiomatic transformation of it (голос -> она). So it is less flexible at building participle constructions of the type used not too often. Maybe that is the reason why the phrase in question sounds a bit unnatural. I don't think it's because of the mentioned redundancy of *слышал+говорящей*, since both versions of

> Я слышал/видел, как она говорит(-ла) по телефону.

(having different meaning) sound *equally* normal to me.